# .pac file and Firefox's network.proxy.socks_remote_dns setting

Tags: proxy, firefox, pac

Does anyone know if Firefox's setting network.proxy.socks_remote_dns would apply to a SOCKS proxy set by a .pac file or only when manually entered in network options? I ask because I use a dynamic ssh tunnel at work and was trying to automate switching with a .pac file but am now worried that the DNS requests will be being made on the work servers.

Comment: Ah. Have found the answer with a little more judicious googling. If anyone's interested: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=386775&p=8300185

Comment: Since you found an answer, you should add the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is to use the SOCKS5 proxy option as per this link:
http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=386775&p=8300185

Comment: FWIW, this doesn't *seem* to work with 3.6 on Linux. I'm not certain i haven't screwed it up somehow, though.